# Visualizar Tabla de Postgresql con PyQt5

Tags: python, postgresql, interfaz-gráfica, pyqt5, qtablewidget

Tengo el siguiente codigo, y he estado intentando visualizar una tabla de *Postgresql-10* con *PyQt5* y no ha sido posible, mi script es:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from windowbd_2 import *
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def loadconection(self):
        self.db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QPSQL')
        self.db.setHostName("localhost")
        self.db.setDatabaseName("Nominapg5")
        self.db.setUserName("postgres")
        self.db.setPassword("12345")
        self.db.open()
        print(self.db.lastError().text())
        return True
        cur = self.db.cursor()
        rows= cur.execute("""select * from admin_eps""")

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(35, 21, 731, 401))
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(6)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(10)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.btn_abrirbd2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_abrirbd2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 460, 75, 23))
        self.btn_abrirbd2.setObjectName("btn_abrirbd2")

        self.btn_abrirbd2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.loadconection(self.admin_eps))

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btn_abrirbd2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Abrirbd2"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Pero al ejecutar el `Pushbuton` no genera error, pero se bloquea y produce el mensaje "Python dejo de funcionar". la consola muestra:

> Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409).  
> Que podria estar sucediendo, agradezco cualquier aporte.

Answer (score 1):

Lo siento, tengo instalado MySQL y tu código se ve así:

```
#from windowbd_2 import *
from PyQt5       import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery
import MySQLdb   as mysql


def convert(in_data):
    def cvt(data):
        try:
            return ast.literal_eval(data)
        except Exception:
            return str(data)
    return tuple(map(cvt, in_data))

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def loadconection(self):
        #                        HostName     UserName           Password      DatabaseName
        db = mysql.connect(host="localhost",user="username", passwd="password",db="testdb")
        with db:
            cur = db.cursor()
            #                             table vvvvvvvvv         
            rows = cur.execute("""select * from pyqt5data""")
            data = cur.fetchall()

            for row in data:
                self.add_table(convert(row))

            cur.close()

    def add_table(self, columns):
        rowPosition = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(rowPosition)         #insert new row
        for i, column in enumerate(columns):
            self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition, i, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(column)))

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(35, 21, 731, 401))
        #self.tableWidget.setRowCount(6)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Id', 'Name', 'Email', 'Phone', 'Note'])
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")

        self.btn_abrirbd2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_abrirbd2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 460, 75, 23))
        self.btn_abrirbd2.setObjectName("btn_abrirbd2")

        #self.btn_abrirbd2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.loadconection(self.admin_eps))
        self.btn_abrirbd2.clicked.connect(self.loadconection)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btn_abrirbd2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Abrirbd2"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta bien tu enfoque, ya lo configure a mi Bd Postgresql, cambie la conexion la configuracion de la tabla, pero se quiebra cuando aplico el boton abrirbd2, error "Python dejo de funcionar". sigue el mismo inconveniente

Comment: Deberia ser mas simple, solo consulta a registros de una tabla, 6 rows y 10 columnas..

Comment: Una pregunta self.tableWidget.insertRow(rowPosition)         #insert new row, que significa, que debo cambiar?

Comment: En algo estoy fallando, pero no se en que

Comment: nota que he cambiado tu línea: self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(10)

Comment: #insert new row - es solo un comentario

Comment: su línea `#self.tableWidget.setRowCount(6)` comente y agregue líneas tantas como registros hay en la base de datos

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76730/discussion-between-jsierra2017-and-s-nick).

Comment: The program, for standard database queries, SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE. The SQLite database was used. https://github.com/skinex/CRUD-SQLite-

Comment: Gracias por tu enlace, me ayuda. a encontrar en parte lo que busco.

Comment: Muy buen ejemplo.

Comment: @Jsierra2017  Echar un vistazo  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63584332/how-to-fetch-data-from-postgresql-using-qlineedit-text-into-qtablewidgit